# SnakeYaml - ClassCastException when deserialising into a map of string and custom objects

Tags: java, deserialization, snakeyaml

I was trying to use SnakeYaml to create a map of string and objects in Java.

There is a **Person.java** class for storing information about a person. I wanted to read the information about each person from a yaml file and store it in a map with the **key** being the **person name** and the **value** being the **Person object**.
ie. For every person name, a person object has to be created and added to the map.

EDIT:
The YAML deserialisation should create a `Map<String, Person>`

Below are the contents of each file:

**YAML file:**

```
PersonName1: 
  value1: foo1
  value2: bar1
  value3: foobar1

PersonName2:
  value1: foo2
  value2: bar2
  value3: foobar2
```

**Person.java**

```
public class Person {
    public String value1;
    public String value2;
    public String value3;
}
```

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("SampleYamlFile.yml"));
        Yaml yaml = new Yaml();

        Map<String, Person> persons = (Map<String, Person>) yaml.load(inputStream);
        for(String key : persons.keySet()) {
            System.out.println("key = " + key);
            Person person = persons.get(key);
            System.out.println("person = " + person);
        }
    }
}
```

The map gets created without any errors. 
The key also gets printed.
But when I try to access the value of the key, I get a **ClassCastException**

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast
>   to Person

Is this type of deserialisation not supported by SnakeYaml?
Any help on why this problem occurs and how this problem can be solved is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
```

to:

```
Yaml yaml = new Yaml(new Constructor(Person.class));
```

Here is a good example how to work with SnakeYaml:
https://aqaexplorer.com/2019/12/10/parsing-yaml-with-snake-yaml/

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, your Yaml file has been decoded in this structure :

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>>
```

You can try this :

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> persons = (Map<String, Map<String, String>>).yaml.load(inputStream);
for(String key : persons.keySet())
{
    System.out.println("key = " + key);
    Map<String, String> personValues = persons.get(key);
    for (String valueKey : personValues.keySet())
    {
        System.out.println(valueKey + " = " + personValues.get(valueKey));
    }
}
```

***edit***

I'm not a specialist of Yaml but to decode data into custom beans, take a look here : https://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation#JavaBeans

Comment: Yep, that's right, it get's decoded in that way. But I wanted it to be created as a Map<String, Person> instead of a Map<String, Map<String, String>>. I will add this explictly in my question.

Answer (score 0):

You need add set() and get(), like this:

```
public class Person {
    public String value1;
    public String value2; 
    public String value3;

    public String getValue1() {
        return value1;
    }

    public void setValue1(String value1) {
        this.value1 = value1;
    }

    public String getValue2() {
        return value2;
    }

    public void setValue2(String value2) {
        this.value2 = value2;
    }

    public String getValue3() {
        return value3;
    }

    public void setValue3(String value3) {
        this.value3 = value3;
    }
}
```